# what is meaning of this python call

Tags: python, cmd, execution

I have an example of Python script `script.py`, which is supposed to take a binary file and convert it to another binary file. In the example, the call is as follows:

```
dir1/file1 -D python dir2/file2 > script.py
```

I thought it will take `file2` from `dir2`, convert and output is as `file1` in `dir` but it is not the case. When I run this script (I ensured the `dir2/file2` exists) nothing happens.

Inside the `script.py` I have the code:

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) <2:
        print >>sys.stderr
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        convert(sys.argv[1])
    except: return1
```

So I assume that the main work is done by some other function `convert`.
What puzzles me is the `cmd` call for this script. 
How to interpret this call?
Is this normal way of calling python functions?

Edit after comments:
Thanks for explanation, the file1 is a binary and it exists on the system. Originally I thought it was created by the script by someone who already did it. From what you say it looks that it is some kind of executable which calls python in the background.

(By the way it is interesting how people downgrade the question if they don't know the answer)

Comment: This doesnt make sense. `dir1/file1 -D python dir2/file2 > script.py` Will run `dir1/file1` as an executable, passing `-D python dir2/file2` as arguments. The stdout of that process is then redirected into a file called `script.py`.

Comment: If this is a shell script command line, the command `dir/file1` is run with arguments `-D`, `python`, and `dir2/file2` with standard output being placed in the file `script.py`. Without more information about the internals of `dir/file1` we have no idea whether it does anything with those arguments, and if so, what exactly.

Comment: @tripleee I beat you by one second ;-)

Comment: Brilliant minds type almost equally fast? Or what's that old saying.

Comment: @TomDalton is it possible that the file1 do some work and the output of this work is passed into script.py? 
I know it is very strange construct but I can't change it

Comment: Running any command with `> script.py` at the end will result in any existing contents of `script.py` being overwritten/replaced. What you're showing only makes sense if `dir1/file1` is an executable that actually writes out python code to its stdout (which is redirected by the `>` into `script.py`).

Comment: Yes, it looks like `file1` is the executable. Previously I thought that it will be binary output, but it is not a case. @TomDalton so the input into `script.py` is not a `file2` I am passing in but something what comes from `file1`?

Comment: @TomDalton do you think that `python` word in the call relates to python as a language? Is there any way to run it this way? I am thinking it can be only a keyword arg for `file1`. I know this convertion can be doen also with Fortran, so maybe there is no Python call as such whatsoever?

Comment: `dir1/file1 -D python` could mean anything, since we don't know what file1 actually does. It's entirely possible that `-D python` tells `file1` to run `python` as a subprocess. Alternatively (and maybe more likely) it could tells `file1` that it has to produce python code as it's output, and you could also run it as `file1 -D java` which would produce java code that does something similar. If you told us the 'real' names of dir1/file1 and dir1/file1 (I am assuming they're not really called this) then we could probably make more educated guesses.

Comment: "So the input into script.py is not a file2 I am passing in but something what comes from file1?". There is no 'input' to `script.py` in the sense that `script.py` is never run directly, it is just a file that gets created as a result of the `>` stdout redirection. The contests on `script.py` after you run the command is exactly the output of the `file1` process. You should be able to see it by just running `dir1/file1 -D python dir2/file2`

Comment: Thanks @TomDalton, it makes more sense now. Basically the `file1` is an executable taking the input `file2`. The output of it is `script.py` which is a python script accustomed to interpret `file2` but in more from the language perspective (it might be a Fortran). Then to actually decode the `file2` it needs to be run as `python script.py file2` and this provides the output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is it normal: The normal way to call python scripts is: `python script_name.py ARGS`, so if what you pasted is made intentionally, it is not normal.
- How to interpret the CMD call: The thing you added is running `file1` with the arguments `-D python dir2/file2` and then redirecting STDOUT to `script.py` So to gain any insight you need to know what file1 is. Try `file --help` or `file --h`, if that does not help, try opening it with `hexdump` or run `strings file1` which will show the literal strings present in the file. They might give you an insight.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `strings file1` indeed shows some output and shade more light. `hexdump` prints bunch of hex showing nothing. The `h` gives invalid option but I think I will get more insight from there.

Comment: Sorry I can't up-vote your answer as it's actually o the point.